# TYPO3 extension news by Georg Ringer - Images in RSS Feed

Tags: image, rss, typo3, feed

I create an RSS news feed with the news extension by Georg Ringer.
All works fine. Except, I didn't find a way yet to display images in the news feed.

Does anybody know how I can build in a image in the xml template file?

I tried something like this:

```
<f:image src="myPath/{mediaElement.image}" />
```

It doesn't work.
Thanks for any help...

TYPO3 6.2.0
news 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Add following somewhere between the item tag in your List.xml template!

```
<content:encoded><f:format.cdata>   
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.mediaPreviews}">
        <f:then>
            <f:alias map="{mediaElement: newsItem.mediaPreviews.0}">
                <f:if condition="{mediaElement.type} == 0">
                    <f:image src="uploads/tx_news/{mediaElement.image}" title="{mediaElement.title}" alt="{mediaElement.alt}" maxWidth="{settings.list.media.image.maxWidth}" maxHeight="{settings.list.media.image.maxHeight}" />
                </f:if>
                <f:if condition="{mediaElement.type} == 1">
                    <f:render partial="Detail/MediaVideo" arguments="{mediaElement: mediaElement}" />
                </f:if>
                <f:if condition="{mediaElement.type} == 2">
                    <f:render partial="Detail/MediaHtml" arguments="{mediaElement: mediaElement}" />
                </f:if>
            </f:alias>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:if condition="{settings.displayDummyIfNoMedia}">
                <f:image src="{settings.list.media.dummyImage}" title="" alt="" maxWidth="{settings.list.media.image.maxWidth}" maxHeight="{settings.list.media.image.maxHeight}" />
            </f:if>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:format.cdata></content:encoded>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code as in the default `List.html` and its partials. The RSS feed does not use a seperate action but is in fact a normal list action!